# SUP Searching data between two dates

Tags: iphone, date, search, sup

I am creating an iPhone application using Sybase unwired platform.In my application I have a screen to search purchase orders according to 'From' and 'To' dates,purchase order number and username.Username is inputing implicitly.If I give username alone the application reads all the purchase orders(PO number) of that user.My problem is when I input the From date and To date alone, the application reads all the PO numbers first time.But second time application reads the actual PO numbers within the dates.I am sure that my Personalization parameters for username,from date and to date are cleared before the synchronization even in the first time.
I could not find what is the problem here.In the login screen I am using this username for login into the application.But after login I cleared the personalization parameter for the username.Can anyone please help.

I am new to SUP
Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are setting the personalization key for date after syncronization methos is called  hence in the next syncronization you are able to get the data according to from and to dates.